# C# неверный ответ, массивы и сортировка

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        int N = int.Parse(input[0]); 
        int M = int.Parse(input[1]); 

        int[] pockets = new int[N]; 
        int[] chests = new int[M]; 

        input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            pockets[i] = int.Parse(input[i]);
        }

        input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            chests[i] = int.Parse(input[i]);
        }

        Array.Sort(pockets); 
        Array.Sort(chests); 

        int operations = 0; 
        int index = N - 1; 

        for (int i = M - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (index < 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (chests[i] >= pockets[index])
            {
                operations++;
                index--;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(operations);
    }
}
```

> Мальчик Вася играет в свою любимую RPG. Он нашел сундук с M ячейками,
> в каждой из которых лежит по одной бутылке с зельем лечения. У его
> героя на поясе есть N карманов, в каждом из которых также лежит по
> одной бутылке. Каждая бутылка восстанавливает фиксированное число
> очков здоровья.
>
> Вася хочет заменить часть бутылок, находящихся в кармане на поясе,
> бутылками из сундука так, чтобы суммарное количество очков здоровья,
> восстанавливаемых бутылками, которые окажутся на поясе после этого,
> было максимальным. Ему доступна одна операция: поменять бутылку из
> указанного кармана пояса с бутылкой из указанной ячейки сундука.
>
> Вам нужно указать минимальное количество операций, после которых
> суммарный запас очков здоровья у Васи на поясе будет максимальным.
>
> Формат ввода Сначала вводятся N, M (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000, 1 ≤ M ≤ 1000).
>
> Далее идут N чисел, причём i-е равно количеству очков здоровья,
> восстанавливаемых бутылкой из i-го кармана пояса.
>
> Далее – M чисел, j-е из которых равно количеству очков здоровья,
> восстанавливаемых бутылкой из j-й ячейки сундука. Все очки –
> натуральные числа, не превосходящие 10000.
>
> Формат вывода Выведите одно число K – минимальное количество операций
> обмена.

При данных на входе:

1. 3 5
2. 19 9 17
3. 22 13 44 11 5

программа выводит 3 вместо 2

Comment: Index не с той стороны запускаете. По бутылям в кармане надо от меньших к большим идти, а вы от больших к меньшим идете